# Firestore get where predicate?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection where each document has a collection of strings 'tags', I'd like to do a query to the firestore collection and get all results where a string appears in the tags array.

Something like:

```
 var { docs } = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('submissions')
            .where((x)=> x.tags.contains('mytag'))
            .get();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: firestore now supports array contains. More info here => https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (yet) query for items where an array contains a certain value. See the [Firestore documentation on working with arrays, lists, and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays), which recommends that you instead model your tags as:

```
tags: {
  mytag: true,
  myothertag: true
}
```

And then query it with:

```
db.collection('submissions')
    .where('tags.mytag', '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(() => {
        // ...
    });
)
```

I also recommend that you read my answer to  [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value), which contains another example. While it is for the Firebase Realtime Database, the same logic applies here.

There is work being done to allow querying an array for a value as you are doing. But as usual: no promises on when this will be available, so keep an eye out on the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) for Firestore updates.